# how to run java script in Geany application?

Tags: javascript, geany

I'm trying to learn programming java script through **"codecademy"**  website.

So i downloaded **Geany** application for more practice but i could not run java script into that application.

I created a .java file into that and wrote my code and compiled but didn't work.

If there is another good app for java script then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly old question but this might help someone else.

If we assume you already installed **Node.js**, you should be able to use **node** CLI tool to run JavaScript files.

In Geany (version 1.33), go to **Build -> Set Build Commands**. At top, you should see **Javascript commands**. Add the name as you want, then add `node "%f"` to the Command textbar .

Now from **Build** tab you can run your file by selecting your customized build option.

Answer (score 0):

Geany is just an IDE:

> Geany is a text editor using the GTK2 toolkit with basic features of an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other packages. It supports many filetypes and has some nice features.

To run **javascript** (not Java <space> script, that could be interpreted as Java, which is another thing) you need of a browser or a javascript engine.

Comment: Thanks.
But can you elaborate it.

Comment: @Raj something specific?

Comment: I wan to create an IP address based form to be filled by students, so student can run that IP in browser on our college network and fill the form, I want to create that forms data base for future.

Comment: @Raj sorry but I can't follow, what has that to do with the original question?